# java concurrent method calls with return value

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, callable, executor

I have previously posted about this topic, but I think I am misunderstanding how concurrent processing works.  I essentially have a servlet with an object that collects data, and whenever a client connects I want to be able to call a method to retrieve data concurrently.  I have tried the following code:

```
public class Test {
    private ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    public Thing getStuff(){

        class Getter implements Callable<Thing>{
            public Thing call(){
                //do collection stuff
                return Thing;
            }
        }

        Callable<Thing> callable = new Getter();
        Future<Thing> future = exec.submit(callable);
        return future.get();   
    }    
}
```

When I try to retrieve the result of a callable, I have to use .get() which prevents subsequent calls to .getStuff() from returning.  I'm assuming this implementation is incorrect, what would be the correct implementation for this functionality?  Thanks.

Comment: `get` will block until the `Callable` completes (and then has something to return)

Comment: You should use a call-back mechanism to notify you when the future's get is ready to be retrieved.

Comment: servlet and Thread? I won't prefer to do. If you have Thread safe single object in JVM could solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct and will run concurrently (up to a concurrence of 10 because that's how big your thread pool is).

The only reason that this would not run concurrently is if you did some synchronization in your call() method (or in a method called by that).

Is it possible that your test method is incorrect and only runs in one thread? If your test looks like this:

```
Test t = new Test();
while (true) {
    t.getStuff();
}
```

then it will only run one instance of getStuff at a time, because your test is single threaded, not because of your server.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can’t have any `Thing` before it exists. So when requesting the resulting `Thing` instance via `get`, the only way to get it, is to wait for the completion of the asynchronous operation to be able to return what that `Callable` returned.

The only way to fix that is not calling `get`, which implies that you can’t return the `Thing` instance as it may be incomplete or even not existing at the time, the `getStuff()` method returns. Otherwise, it’s simply not an asynchronous operation.

Therefore, the caller has to deal with the asynchronous nature of the operation as well. Either, `getStuff()` returns the `Future` representing the ongoing operation or the caller passes the code which will process the result via a parameter object to `getStuff()`, so it can be executed asynchronous as well.

Putting it simply, the entire idea of asynchronous processing is to be able to do something else while the asynchronous operation is running. If in your application, all you can do, is to wait for the result of the operation, there is no point in doing it asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet from your example submits a new `Getter` task to a pool thread, and then *immediately* waits for the pool thread to complete the task:

```
Callable<Thing> callable = new Getter();
Future<Thing> future = exec.submit(callable);
return future.get();
```

What's the point in that?  Why not just perform the `Getter` task in the current thread:

```
return new Getter().call();
```

The entire point of giving the task to a pool thread is so that the current thread can *do something else* while the pool thread is working.

```
Callable<Thing> callable = new Getter();
Future<Thing> future = exec.submit(callable);
doSomethingElseThatTakesAWhile();
return future.get();
```